# Update Shopify product price using StorefrontAPI

Tags: next.js, graphql, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

I want to compute some conditions based on the user's choices in the front end and update the product price of that variant in Shopify via a GraphQl mutation. Is it possible with the Storefront API setup? FYI I'm using Nexjs Commerce to set up my store. I don't want to include Admin Api just for this one feature, please do suggest alternative solutions if there are any!

Comment: I don't think it's possible using `Storefront API`. you need to somehow use Admin Api

Comment: hey, seems like it. Using Rest version Admin Api for this update,thanks!

Comment: sure, your welcome 